# An increase of/in serotonin

Tags: prepositions, style

Are both options correct? If so, are there some subtle differences between those?

> An increase of serotonin

> An increase in serotonin

Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell us where you found them and what difference you think they have so someone might help you better?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'm preparing for the IELTS test by writing some mock essays. After I wrote the following sentence, "Studies show that establishing meaningful connections with other animals brings about an increase of serotonin", a grammar correction app suggested changing the preposition "of" to "in" and I'm curious why and is it critical.